# Chemical structure of water-soluble polysaccharide

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, carbohydrates

I don't know much about analytical chemistry, but I need to determine the chemical structure of a water soluble polysaccharide which is not pure and may have D-glucose, mannose and fructose. How do I actually know its chemical structure?

It's from a plant and I know it has fructan and a random polysaccharide which consists of glucose and mannose as the main part and it also has less than 20% impurities such as ash, fat, protein or other sugars. I need to know the arrangement between monosaccharides in the random polymer and the percentage of each polysaccharide.

I have read that it's amorph and linear but I'd rather to check if it is branched. The compound can be consumed with the testing.

Comment: Megazyme has several kits to analyze different polysaccharides. If you only need to do the analysis a few times, you can also download the manual for the kit, buy the necessary reagents locally and follow the procedure. http://www.megazyme.com/docs/default-source/artwork/product-list-for-web-may-2014.pdf?sfvrsn=2

Comment: Thank you but I want to know if I need to use NMR, IR, Mass spectrometry.... and how the procedure is.

Comment: Because you are dealing with a polymer, $^1H$ and $^{13}C$ NMR might be able to tell you the ratio of glucose, fructose and mannose (if the peaks separate), IR might allow you to determine the amount of branching (along with NMR), but MS won't be of much help. Depending on the impurities, they may need to be removed. Polysaccharides are slightly soluble in ethanol, so you can purify the polysaccharides by dissolving in a minimum amount of water, precipitating the proteins first with trichloroacetic acid, filter, then add 3 volumes of ethanol and filtering the precipitated polysaccharides.

Comment: Could you digest the polysaccharide into monosaccharides and run on HPLC and compare to known standards? Would get you the percent of each component, but not the sequence.

Comment: Depending on the impurities and the length of the sugars, LC-MS (Liquid Chromatography-Mass Spectrometry) would be an option. Comercial Mass Spectrometers can be coupled to a database to quickly find fractured mono sacharides. That way you know the composition. The order in which the polysacharides are made up is not as easy, but I can assure you it will be very chalenging using Spectroscopy to find the answer to that.